# Ignore file events (create, modify, delete) with WatchService

Tags: java, events, watchservice

For my current side project I need to utilize a WatchService to track events in a given directory. My code is yet mainly based off of [Oracles WatchService tutorial example](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/examples/WatchDir.java)

I however need it to be limited to **folder** only events (e.g ENTRY_CREATE C:\temp\folder_a).

What I'm trying to do is to take an initial Snapshot of the directory's content
and store each contents path into either *dirCache* or *fileCache*

If an new event is registered this should be checked:

- is event context a file in *fileCache* or
- is event context a new file (-> Files.isRegularFile)

so both new File events should be discarded or events from files that are already in the cache.

But printing out the events produces

> ENTRY_DELETE: C:\temp\k.txt

for files but no ENTRY_CREATE or ENTRY_MODIFY.

What am I doing wrong? Am I not checking against the cache correctly or is it something completely different?

Here's the current code base:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            new DirectoryWatcher(Paths.get("C:\\temp")).processEvents();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

*DirectoryWatcher* Class

```
package service;

import static java.nio.file.StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_CREATE;
import static java.nio.file.StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_DELETE;
import static java.nio.file.StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_MODIFY;
import static java.nio.file.StandardWatchEventKinds.OVERFLOW;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.FileSystems;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.WatchEvent;
import java.nio.file.WatchEvent.Kind;
import java.nio.file.WatchKey;
import java.nio.file.WatchService;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

/**
 * Slightly modified version of Oracle
 * example file WatchDir.java
 * /

public class DirectoryWatcher {
    private final Path path;
    private final WatchService watcher;
    private final Map<WatchKey,Path> keys;
    private PathSnapshot pathSnapshot;
    private boolean trace = false;

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
static <T> WatchEvent<T> cast(WatchEvent<?> event) {
    return (WatchEvent<T>)event;
}

/**
 * Register the given directory with the WatchService
 */
private void register(Path dir) throws IOException {
    WatchKey key = dir.register(watcher, ENTRY_CREATE, ENTRY_DELETE, ENTRY_MODIFY);
    if (trace) {
        Path prev = keys.get(key);
        if (prev == null) {
            System.out.format("register: %s\n", dir);
        } else {
            if (!dir.equals(prev)) {
                System.out.format("update: %s -> %s\n", prev, dir);
            }
        }
    }
    keys.put(key, dir);
}

public DirectoryWatcher(Path dir) throws IOException {
    this.watcher = FileSystems.getDefault().newWatchService();
    this.keys = new HashMap<WatchKey,Path>();
    this.path = dir;
    this.pathSnapshot = new PathSnapshot(dir);

    register(dir);
    // enable trace after initial registration
    this.trace = true;
}

/**
 * Process all events for keys queued to the watcher
 */
void processEvents() {
    for (;;) {

        // wait for key to be signaled
        WatchKey key;
        try {
            key = watcher.take();
        } catch (InterruptedException x) {
            return;
        }

        Path dir = keys.get(key);
        if (dir == null) {
            System.err.println("WatchKey not recognized!!");
            continue;
        }

        for (WatchEvent<?> event: key.pollEvents()) {
            Kind<?> kind = event.kind();

            // TBD - provide example of how OVERFLOW event is handled
            if (kind == OVERFLOW) {
                continue;
            }

            // Context for directory entry event is the file name of entry
            WatchEvent<Path> ev = cast(event);
            Path name = ev.context();
            Path child = dir.resolve(name);
            this.updateDirContent();
            /*
             * currently: creating file events are neglected 
             * but deleting a file creates an event which is printed
             * TODO: disregard delete event if sent from file
             */
            boolean isFile = Files.isRegularFile(child);
            if (pathSnapshot.isInFileCache(child)|| isFile) {
                //disregard the event if file
                event = null;
            } else {
                // print out event
                System.out.format("%s: %s\n", event.kind().name(), child);
            }
        }

        // reset key and remove from set if directory no longer accessible
        boolean valid = key.reset();
        if (!valid) {
            keys.remove(key);
            // all directories are inaccessible
            if (keys.isEmpty()) {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}

private void updateDirContent() {
    this.pathSnapshot = pathSnapshot.updateSnapshot(path);

}
}
```

*PathSnapshot* Class

```
package service;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class PathSnapshot {
    public ArrayList<Path> dirCache = new ArrayList<Path>();
    public ArrayList<Path> fileCache = new ArrayList<Path>();

    public PathSnapshot(Path dir) {
        try {
            Stream<Path> rawDirContent = Files.walk(
                    dir, 1);

            Object[] dirContent = rawDirContent.toArray();
            rawDirContent.close();

            sortIntoCache(dirContent, dir);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void sortIntoCache(Object[] dirContent, Path rootdir) {
        for (Object object : dirContent) {
            //create path from element
            Path objectPath = Paths.get(object.toString());
            //skip start path / the root directory
            if (object.equals(rootdir)) {
                continue;
            } else if (Files.isRegularFile(objectPath)) {
                fileCache.add(objectPath);
            } else if (Files.isDirectory(objectPath)) {
                dirCache.add(objectPath);
            }
        } 
    }

    public boolean isInFileCache(Path path) {
        if (fileCache.contains(path)) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public boolean isInDirCache(Path path) {
        if (dirCache.contains(path)) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public PathSnapshot updateSnapshot(Path dir){
        return new PathSnapshot(dir);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are listening to all possible events from the file system so there isn't more to ask for. Java can't do anything if the OS isn't presenting more events and in more detail. Some complex file system operations are just not represented by one event but of a sequence of basic events. So you have to make the best out of the events and have to interpret what a sequence of events actually means.

Comment: But shouldn't my own implementation work though? If a file is created I update the *PathSnapshot* and if an deletion event occurs the context would be something like "C:\temp\a_file.txt" if this is checked against the fileCache it is registered as a file event and discarded.